# Asking for Shipping Method per seller?

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, shopping-cart

I'm currently working on a cart page and checkout flow for a marketplace that aggregates different sellers (e.g the user can purchase from different sellers and preform one checkout for all item). shipping method selection is done on a seller level . at what stage should the user select a shipping method ( standard , expedited ). checkout or cart ?
Adding another stage ( for selection)  to the checkout seems like too much.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the shipping method will affect how much the customer pays, I would allow them to make that selection in the cart, or as early as possible in the checkout process. Assuming you will be asking them for a delivery address during the checkout, it would make sense to ask for the shipping method on the same page.